# Syntax and library features to avoid in C++ programs that are planned to be ported to Rust

Tags: c++, rust, porting

I am working on a small C++ (C++17 in this case) program that I plan to port to Rust in the future (without dropping the C++ version). This program uses hardly any libraries. It also uses very little functionality from the STL, only `std::function` at the moment.

Apart from recommendations already in the general C++ guidelines, Is there any specific syntax construct I should avoid in C++ because it would make porting to Rust especially hard?

If I would need more functionality from the STL, are there any specific STL classes that are notable trouble makers when porting to Rust?

**UPDATE:** I exclude legacy C++ code in this question because it would make this question to broad. If someone is interested anyway, then please raise that specific question yourself.

Comment: When *porting* it to Rust, you most likely won't use the same abstractions, so why bother? And also, why do you want to maintain 2 separates projects doing the same thing?

Comment: Rust and C++ use different paradigm, so that hard to say. I would recommand to avoid heavy template use.

Comment: You could write the C++ in the Functional style.

Comment: @Demolishun and At Stgargateur. Functional style sounds good but that is one of the reasons of my code being fairly heavy on templates. Hence both of you together make me pesimistic.

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios. Do I understand correctly and there are many abstractions you can implemenent in C++ but not Rust?

Comment: Rust is data-oriented, functional, and RAII-heavy. You can do all those things in C++, but the compiler won't stop you from veering from doing things not allowed in Rust. Rust will, so it will be a challenge to make them line up.

Comment: @parktomatomi. I do not consider having to be RAII-clean as a porting problem but rather a backporting opportunity if at all it arises with modern C++. But you are right regarding legacy code which I will exclude from the question now.